# What plants is Jesus referring to in Matthew 15:13

Tags: matthew, gospels

> “He answered, "Every plant that my heavenly Father has not planted will be rooted up.”
>   ‭‭Matthew‬ ‭15:13‬ ‭

Concerning what plant exactly is this referring to? A biological plant, the Word of God (seed Matthew 13) or both?

Comment: Neither. He's talking about the Pharisees, using plant as a metaphor. Since their faith is false, they are not planted by the Father, and therefore will be rooted up. This kind of imagery is pretty common through the Bible from Psalm 1 to John 15.

Comment: The Pharisees are plants. Like the wheat and the tares. Or let all the trees clap for joy.

Comment: _...that they might be called trees of righteousness, the planting of the LORD, that he might be glorified._ Isaiah 61:3. But these, specifically, were not so. And would be pulled up.

Answer (score 1):

It is a metaphor, so as a metaphor it does not directly relate to the actual thing said (namely, the biological plant), for all biological plants are planted and grow by God, the Creator of nature.

Then, what is that "plant" that is not planted by God if all biological plants are so planted? Surely, the non-biological "plants". But what are those non-biological plants not planted by God? It is tempting to say that evil and hypocritical teachers, the Sadducees and Pharisees, or all evil and deceitful men, who became evil by abusing their free will.

But it is blatantly wrong! For any man's being is fashioned by God and He sustains into being all, even the most evil of men being long-suffering to them, always willing them to repent. Thus all men are planted and sustained by God. But then what are those other "plants" not planted by God?

What remains is the evil deeds and choices of men, for they are indeed the "plants" not planted by God, and those "plants" lack ontological ground, for evil is deviation from the fullness of being, and as a deviation it is a non-being or quasi-being, and it will be sooner or later discovered and understood as such by an evildoer, and if he will have enough courage and faith in the all-merciful Lord, then he will repent and submit those sinful deeds and words to the consuming fire of the divine Mercy and Compassion (Hebrews 12:29), for only the good has ontological grounding and eternal future, whereas all evil as non-being will perish. God wishes to burn not men, created in His image and likeness, but the infection of evil in them through their responsive co-action and repentance, that is why also the Psalmist says "the way of the wicked will perish" (Psalm 1:4-6), - he does not say "the wicked will perish", but that the "way of the wicked will perish" so that the wicked may repent and turn away from this perishable way.

However, repentance is not automatic and necessary, depending on a sinner's free will and initiative, otherwise he runs a danger of falling out eternally from the Kingdom of Heaven, and eternally identify himself with those plants not planted by God, that is to say, his own sinful deeds, words and decisions - the non-realities; and this is what the eternal torment of hell means.

Comment: Psalm 68:2, 9:5, 11:10, 37:20 Ezekiel 3:18, 33:8... All of these say that the wicked will perish. Even Psalm 1:6 you quoted I read the way of the wicked leads to destruction. The wicked do wicked deeds therefore they are wicked. Bad trees produce bad fruits. “Let them alone; they are blind guides. *And if the blind lead the blind, both will fall into a pit."”
‭‭Matthew‬ ‭15:14‬* I however can still agree with the idea that you are proposing because it’s out of the heart that all this wickedness comes and God says He will give us a new heart. So transplanting the wicked heart... ‭

Comment: The heart being the soil and the laws of God that He will put on our hearts is the Word of God. So the plants are the results of the teachings, either the teachings of the wicked and bad soil producing bad plants with bad fruits not of God or good heart with God’s laws and good plants producing good fruits. Son give me your heart for from it comes the fountain of life. What you treasure that is what will be in your heart. So in a sense the Pharisees were identified with their deeds/fruits and therefore the plants producing the fruits. I guess I can agree with you. Sorry just thinking out loud.

Comment: @Autodidact Thanks. I guess we agree, and it is the New Testament law not to identify a sin with a sinner; otherwise it will be nonsense to pray for the sinners, for such prayer is nothing else than that we wish that they may repent; but is there any time when a sinner is so much sinful that he and the sin are to be identified and so we cease to pray already for him? No! There is no such time, for a the two are always to be distinguished: any sinner carries divine image and thus is planted by God being potentially a heir of Kingdom, yet sin is not planted by God and will be eradicated forever.

Comment: And yet... *“I tell you this, brothers: flesh and blood cannot inherit the kingdom of God, nor does the perishable inherit the imperishable.”
‭‭1 Corinthians‬ ‭15:50‬* Not sure we agree. The flesh is corrupted.

Comment: @Autodidact I cannot fathom what you mean by “flesh is corrupted”; indeed it is and that is true for all fallen humankind; and exactly to this fallen and sinful humankind did God-Logos descend and became man, because He did not identify falledness of human nature with the human nature. And this is His teaching that neither we should treat fleshly, sinful humans as enemies, but pray for them and wish them come to repentance and to Christ. If we identify them with fleshly-ness and sin not admitting in them a potential for repentance, then we ourselves have fallen away from Christ’s discipleship.

Comment: Let me put it differently. Upon being saved, We receive a new spirit, our soul is being renewed, and the body will be renewed after we die.

Comment: @Autodidact When we are born anew in Holy Spirit our fleshly desires and inclinations ("the body of sin" /Romans 6:6/) are transformed and directed from temporal to the eternal things. Yes 100%. However, every man, every even a great sinner has a potentiality, through co-action with divine Grace, to get transformed. We should always wish all sinners to get to the latter state, for it is Christ's eternal will for them, and we should imitate Christ (1 Cor. 11:1). Surely, this eternal will of Christ can remain unfulfilled, unless a sinner collaborates with it out of free initiative of repentance.